# What programming language is that?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe, web

Can anybody help me about what programming language that coult be?

```
<td>
        {
        IF [§HTMLBILD IS NOT NULL§] THEN
            <img src="[§HTMLBILD§]">
        ELSE
            [§ISBN§]
        }
</td>
```

It is placed in HTML files and runs in an Window (iFrame?) inside of an Windows application. But I'm not familiar with it. It's no VBSCRIPT, JAVASCRIPT but I really need to add some functionallity...

I tried to use some extra JavaScript but because this Language also uses the same brackets {} all the javascript gets replaced by a error message: "**** Fehler 3515 beim Auswerten der Bedingung !" (Sorry it's German ...)

[§VARIABLENAME§] ... are some Values that get passed on by the Windows Application!

Comment: Please don't cross-post (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/267350/what-programming-language-ist-this).

Comment: Please don't ask questions that you already know won't be received well.

Comment: If you tried to extend that page with JavaScript, and that triggered an error which you want to resolve, why didn't you include the JavaScript in your code example? It appears that you're asking several questions at the same time.

Comment: Fourth, where do all these tags come into the picture (`iframe`, `internet-explorer`)?

Comment: I used those tags because when i right click on the frame that holds the generated HTML page in the windows application i get the same context menu  as in internet explorer. So my guess was that this engine is used to render the HTML. I also tried to catch the request/response with fiddler, but it seems that all is handled within the application. I just mentioned the JS because i thought that somebody might recognize the pattern of the error message.

Comment: As this seems to be the wrong base to post such a question, do you have any reccomendation where I could post something like this to get help?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's a company-specific or application-specific language someone has written. It looks pretty lousy. There might not be a way to prevent it interpreting `{`..`}` in the source, so to work around the problem of it conflicting with JavaScript, you will probably need to put your JavaScript in external files rather than embedding it in the HTML.